# Calculate total by group in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a small php program which is used to display all the pending amount for each staff member but I’m having some problems totaling the group values for the acc_code.

I have explained the system below.  Each staff is assigned an acc_code. Each account code has 40 – 50 staff members

eg:

```
admission  name   months  acc_code
==================================
001        test1  3       10A
002        test2  5       10A
006        test3  7       15B
008        test4  1       15A
011        test5  2       16C
051        test6  3       16A
012        test7  3       16A
```

Expected output:

```
 admission  name   months  acc_code
    ==================================
    001        test1  3       10A
    002        test2  5       10A
                    Total    USD 1000

    006        test3  7       15B
                    Total    USD 1800

    008        test4  1       15A
                    Total    USD 800

    011        test5  2       16C
                    Total    USD 1600

    051        test6  3       16A
    012        test7  3       16A
                     Total    USD 2700
```

Each staff has a certain amount assigned.  I need to get the total pending amount for each acc_code

Below is the code I have written but I’m unsure how to get the grand total for each ac_code

```
select
  (period_diff(date_format(now(), '%Y%m'),
  date_format(month, '%Y%m'))) as months,
  pending.amount,
  pending.admission_numb,
  pending.month,
  staff.full_name,
  staff.acc_code
from
  pending join staff 
  on pending.admission_numb = staff.admission 
group by
  admission
order by
  staff.acc_code asc
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  staff.acc_code,
  SUM(pending.amount) pending_amount
from
  pending join staff 
  on pending.admission_numb = staff.admission 
group by
  staff.acc_code
order by
  staff.acc_code asc
```

Comment: grouping by staff.acc_code doesn't show the individual records. need the individual records (as in my code) and the total value for each acc_code

Answer (score 0):

You need to GROUP BY acc_code and SUM months. Something like this:

```
select SUM ((period_diff(date_format(now(), '%Y%m'), date_format(month, '%Y%m'))) as months),
pending.amount, pending.admission_numb, pending.month, staff.full_name, staff.acc_code
from pending join staff 
on pending.admission_numb = staff.admission 
group by staff.acc_code order by staff.acc_code asc
```

Please note that I didn't review your query. I just added the stuff i think you're missing.
And what do you need the staff's name for when you're trying to get results for the group?

Comment: i need to show the individual record per acc_code whhich i have done in my code and i need only the each total for each acc_code. grouping bt acc_code doesnt work. and i need to sum the pending.amount for each acc_c not months.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question with a expected result table (the way you want to appear, write it manually) cause I can't understand what you really need.

Comment: i have added the expected output. Thanks

Comment: You can't have different rows in one mysql result set, so the expected result is impossible. Instead you can have something like this:
`001        test1  3       10A   1000`;
`002        test2  5       10A   1000` etc. which can be achieved, I believe, by @Tom's last answer. That's the rigth approach. If it still can't produce some result, the problem is in some minor details in the query, which we can not resolve unless we have the database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get totals for acc_code.

```
select
  (period_diff(date_format(now(), '%Y%m'),
  date_format(month, '%Y%m'))) as months,
  pending.amount,
  pending.admission_numb,
  pending.month,
  staff.full_name,
  staff.acc_code,
  (SELECT SUM(pending.amount) FROM pending p join staff s on p.admission_numb = s.admission WHERE p.acc_code = staff.acc_code) acc_code_total_pending
from
  pending join staff 
  on pending.admission_numb = staff.admission 
group by
  admission
order by
  staff.acc_code asc
```